# json_encode error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, arrays, json, implode

I have a json_encode element and i have to implode it like that

```
<?php
$user = json_decode($var);
$fetch_array = implode(",", $user);
?>
```

with the debug print_f the array result like that

```
Array( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [name] => Elis ) 
       [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [name] => Eilbert ))1
```

it result a error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

My goal is use this json array with the statment SELECT IN on mysql,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN $user
```

I tought that i have to implode it. if I delete the function implode it show me (array,array)

How can i do that?

Comment: Show please source json string and result you expect

Answer (score 5):

json_decode returns an object by default. In your case, you need an array. Add 2nd param as true as below:

```
json_decode($var, true);
```

Comment: if i put the second parameter true it show me this error:  Array to string conversion

Comment: Why do you have implode.? Its not needed. json_decode returns an array.

Comment: My goal is use this json array with the statment SELECT IN on mysql, I tought that i have to implode it. if I delete the function implode it show me (array,array)

Comment: sorry man. You need implode to convert array to comma delimited string. Then you can use inside mysql query.